# Passagem de argumento por array PHP

Tags: php

Salve pessoal, tenho a seguinte função

```
exec($dia, $mes, $ano);
```

gostaria de fazer um `foreach` para executa-la através de uma base em array. Passei da seguinte forma

```
$a=array("1,2,2016", "2,2,2016","3,2,2016");

foreach($a as $as){ exec($as) };
```

Mas apresenta o erro do segundo argumento em diante:

> Missing argument

como posso fazer para passar esses parâmetros?

Comment: O problema é chamada da função, precisa obrigatóriamente de 3 argumentos, se são opcionais, coloque eles na assinatura como null

Comment: exato queria que cada linha do array representasse os argumentos, que o 1 fosse referente ao $dia, 2 $mes e 2016 $ano em cada linha do array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A partir do PHP 5.6, você pode utilizar o [argument unpacking](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list.new)

```
function exec($dia, $mes, $ano){
    // faz algo
}

$as = [
    [1, 2, 2016], 
    [2, 2, 2016], 
    [3, 2, 2016],
];

foreach($as as $a){ 
  exec(...$a);
};
```

Comment: Eu estava pensando nisso haha +1

Answer (score 3):

O problema é chamada da função, precisa obrigatóriamente de 3 argumentos, para passar eles pode transformar essa string em um array com `explode()` e passar cada um individualmente.

```
$a = array("1,2,2016", "2,2,2016","3,2,2016");

foreach($a as $as){
    $param = explode(',', $as);
    exec($param[0], $param[1], $param[2]);
}
```

Outra forma de fazer

```
function nova(){
    list($d, $m, $y) =  explode(',',  func_get_args()[0]);
    echo "$d/$m/$y <br>";
}


$a=array("1,2,2016", "2,2,2016","3,2,2016");

foreach($a as $as){
    nova($as);
}
```

Comment: ah, saquei vou alterar e testar aqui.... vlw mesmo

Answer (score 2):

Só pra constar, uma variante da resposta do @rray:

```
$a = array(
   array( '1', '2', '2016' ),
   array( '2', '2', '2016' ),
   array( '3', '2', '2016' )
);

foreach($a as $as){
    exec( $as[0], $as[1], $as[2] );
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Como o PHP é muito "flexível" dá até para fazer assim:

```
$a = ["1,2,2016", "2,2,2016","3,2,2016"];

foreach($a as $as){
    eval('exec('.$as.');');
}
```